# error CS0103: The name 'SetSolvedState' does not exist in the current context

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Hello all there is an error in the code and I do not know how to solve it. Here is the code itself.

```
if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.F))
        {
            if (dotRight >= threshold && dotup >= threshold)
            {
                SetSolvedState(true);
            }
            else
            {
                SetSolvedState(false);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Make sure a method called SetSolvedState is accessible to wherever this code is

Comment: The code block belongs to some class. That class or it's parent doesn't have such method `SetSolvedStatus`, or as mentioned in the comment above, visibility is insufficient (private?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message tells you what your problem is: The method "SetSolvedState" does not exist or can't be accessed. So you have to create it or if it's already defined, you have to check why it can't be used. As example, it could be private and must be protected or even public instead. If you are not able to find out your problem on your own, you please have to add your entire project because it's not possible to see the problem with just these lines of code.